# MonoTouch - equivalents of Docking and Anchoring in iOS UI

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, size, resolution

In .NET WinForms, I use anchors and docking a lot to maintain the proportions consistent with different window sizes and screen resolutions.

From my understanding, resolution of iOS devices can also differ.

So what's used in iOS to maintain proportions of the UI elements to make them look consistent on various screen resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling) link.

In general you use `UIAutoresizingMask` to do this, although it is vastly different from WinForms or WPF.  I use Interface Builder (XCode) for my view layouts, which I feel makes it somewhat easier (they have a nice interactive video when you change layout settings).

If you go the route of setting up your views from C#, it will be the same--you just set `UIAutoresizingMask` by hand.